# ¿Cómo compilar correctamente en Vala cuando utilizo 2 o más packages?

Tags: gtk, vala

Mi problema es cómo poder realizar la compilación correctamente para que pueda ejecutar correctamente mi programa, ya que estoy utilizando posix y gio-2.0.
Aquí está código:

```
using GLib;
static void main ()
{
    int value;
    string path_file = "/tmp/archivo.txt";


    value = global::Posix.system("Comando");    //Lo uso para enviar la   salida de un comando a un archivo, en este caso path

    File file = File.new_for_path (path_file); //Lo uso para poder leer los datos enviados por el comando.
    try {
        FileInputStream @is = file.read ();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream (@is);
        string linea;

        while ((linea = dis.read_line ()) != null) {
            stdout.printf ("%s\n", linea);
        }
    } catch (Error e) {
        stdout.printf ("Error: %s\n", e.message);
    }
}
```

Para poder compilar:
    `valac archivo.vala -o ejecutable --pkg gio-2.0 posix`

Pero al colocar por ejemplo:
`valac archivo.vala -o ejecutable --pkg LOS_PAQUETES` me aparecen varias errores en la compilación, o sea que estoy realizando mal la compilación.
  ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea para que pueda realizarlo bien?

Comment: ¿Que errores te muestra?, podrias agregarlos a tu pregunta.

Comment: No agregué lo que me reportaba la terminal porque pensé que la iba a hacer extensa a la pregunta. Acá lo que me arroja:
Cuando ejecuto esto `valac archivo.vala -o ejecutable --pkg posix` ocurre esto: 
```archivo.vala:10.2-10.5: error: The type name `File' could not be     found
 File file = File.new_for_path (path_file);
 ^^^^
    archivo.vala:12.3-12.17: error: The type name `FileInputStream' could not be found```

Eso son algunos de los mensajes que me arroja, y si en vez de --pkg posix pongo --pkg gio-2.0 me arroja otros errores. Perdón si se vve desacomodado pero así se muestra acá.

Comment: Pero ya lo solucioné, simplemente tengo que poner otro argumento:
`valac archivo.vala -o ejecutable --pkg posix --pkg gio-2.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con [vala](/questions/tagged/vala) y su compilador `valac` es necesario que especifiques por separado cada uno de los paquetes que vas a utilizar con la directiva `--pkg`.

```
valac -o ejecutable --pkg gio-2.0 --pkg posix archivo.vala
```

Como buena práctica es recomendable que al principio especifiques las opciones para compilar como `--pkg`, `-C`, `-o` o `-g` y final especifiques el archivo.

Si quieres explorar más opciones y el funcionamiento del compilador te recomiendo leer el manual de `valac` con la terminal:

```
$ man valac
```

Comment: Gracias, tendré más en cuenta el orden de los argumentos y el manual ;)